# How to get column value of grid in C# Windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid

How to get  column value of grid in C# Windows application?

When I clicked on the cell, at that time it should get column values.

```
private void gridAgentDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.gridAgentDetails.CurrentRowIndex; i++)
    {
        string str = gridAgentDetails.Text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking about `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` ??

Comment: @Akaram, i think rams is using DataGrid control in WPF. It's not a Form application.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value`:

```
String result = this.gridviewAgentDetails.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

---

[DataGridView.CurrentCell Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) gets the currently active cell.

[DataGridViewCell.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) gets the value associated with this cell.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Values of the Selected Cells Follow the Below Code

```
int CNo = datagrid.CurrentCellAddress.Y;

int StNum = (int)datagrid.Rows[CNo].Cells[0].Value;

string StName = (string)datagrid.Rows[CNo].Cells[1].Value;

int MrksSecured = (int)datagrid.Rows[CNo].Cells[2].Value;
```

Comment: i am asking datagrid not gridview.

Answer (score 0):

try this eventHandler: [I tried with this and i got result]

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
        MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: i am asking datagrid not gridview.

Comment: read this article once to know the difference between datagrid and gridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you comment saying you're using **DataGrid**, this is a WPF application, not a Form application.

WPF DataGrid Control is visual representation of data, you cannot read a specific cell directly out of a **DataGrid**, Hence you cannot select a specific row or column on a **DataGrid**, unless you bind it to a data source.

**DataGrid** is designed to use with **DataTable**. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) to see how **DataGrid** is binded to **DataTable**.

Then, to read a specific cell value in DataGrid, you would read the DataTable instead (e.g. `dataTable1[RowNumber][ColumnName]` where RowNumber is an int, and ColumnName is a string.